# deploy static web project into google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

how to deploy static web project into google cloud, i am using eclipse and have created static web project, i want to deploy this into google cloud from eclipse, i have created a google web project, but it is dynamic nature, but i would need to deploy as static web application. is there a way to deploy static web application into google app engine? attached my static page, which i need to convert into google app engine format

[image]

Comment: Just create a new AppEngine project and put everythingn from WebContent in /src/main/webapp

Comment: Have you tried Googling "deploy static web project into google cloud"? There are quite a few resources on doing just that. You can even use [Google Cloud Storage to host your site](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration?hl=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Configure a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a static website with the domain have by following the guide at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration.

2- Upload your white paper as objects to your new Google Cloud Storage bucket to be made available on the web as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new google-cloud-module. Place all your code in the `src\main\webapp` folder
Add this to your `web.xml` file -

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The `web.xml` file resides in the `webapp\WEB-INF` folder.